# Yum broken on RHEL 6

Tags: yum, rhel6

Using 64-bit RHEL 6, receiving this error from Yum:

```
[root /]# yum install [package_name]

---Start Error---
<BR><BR>
Traceback (most recent call last):<BR>

       File "/usr/bin/yum", line 29, in <module> 
       yummain.user_main(sys.argv[1:], exit_code=True) 
       File "/usr/share/yum-cli/yummain.py", line 288, in user_main 
       errcode = main(args) 
       File "/usr/share/yum-cli/yummain.py", line 140, in main 
       result, resultmsgs = base.doCommands() 
       File "/usr/share/yum-cli/cli.py", line 436, in doCommands 
       self._getTs(needTsRemove) 
       File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/yum/depsolve.py", line 99, in _getTs 
       self._getTsInfo(remove_only) 
       File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/yum/depsolve.py", line 110, in _getTsInfo 
       pkgSack = self.pkgSack 
       File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/yum/__init__.py", line 887, in <lambda> 
       pkgSack = property(fget=lambda self: self._getSacks(), 
       File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/yum/__init__.py", line 669, in _getSacks 
       self.repos.populateSack(which=repos) 
       File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/yum/repos.py", line 308, in populateSack 
       sack.populate(repo, mdtype, callback, cacheonly) 
       File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/yum/yumRepo.py", line 187, in populate 
       dobj = repo_cache_function(xml, csum) 
       File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/sqlitecachec.py", line 46, in getPrimary 
       self.repoid)) 
    TypeError: Parsing primary.xml error: Start tag expected, '<' not found 


---End Error---
```

Just started today. Was working just fine a couple days ago. Haven't installed anything on this system since last use.

Have already rebuilt Python 2.6 and Yum 3.4.3. Still same errors as above. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Clear the repo cache and rebuild it

```
yum clean all
yum update
```

Comment: Tried that already. "_yum clean all_" succeeds, but "_yum update_" [after loading some repos] fails with error output above.

Comment: Check this http://www.ephur.net/search/typeerror+parsing+primary+xml+error+start+tag+expected+not+found/

Comment: NOTE:Maybe you should move this thread to unix and linux forum. It looks like a distro issue.

Comment: Thanks for the "ephur" link. That appears to have worked. Only confusing part is... the file that I moved (rather than deleted) was placed there on March 15th. Why would it start barking now? Very confusing.

Comment: That link does not work. Maybe it is this one http://www.ephur.net/index.php?s=yum+xml+start+tag

Comment: That link was posted 3 months ago, links are not eternal unfortunately, I had found it searching on google :)

Comment: @rMistero Then please share what you found for others.

Answer (score 0):

Run this:

```
sudo su
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib64:/usr/local/lib
yum clean all
yum update yum
```

I think this fixes it. It worked for me.